# US Dropbox : For parents and kids in single dropbox appointment?

Tags: us-visa

Me and my spouse are eligible for dropbox as our US L1 and L2 visa renewal. we have 2 y/o kids who would be needing fresh US L2 visas. Since we are doing our visa renewal as dropbox, can the kids' L2 visa be done as dropbox in one single appointment?